# Media queries not applied even if the screen size matches

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this issue: when the screen is at the right size (in this case, under 768px), the mediaquery isn't applied.

Here is my element:

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row ">
   ...
</div>
```

Here are the classes:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-md-row {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

These are how they are applied according to Chrome Webdev Tools:
[image: how chrome applies the classes]

And yes, I have this tag in my "head":
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Since everything matches, why isn't "flex-column" applied instead of "flex-md-row".

Comment: They are applied the right way round on my Chrome (Windows 10). What system are you on? And is the code you have shown exactly what you are running? (ie the column setting being after the media query)?

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the cascading soul of CSS
you have said in `.flex-md-row` that above 768px `flex-direction` should have `row` value

But

below that you said (inside `.flex-column`) that in any size `flex-direction` should have `column` value

and you set both classes to your html element...
Here in CSS the latter will win the rival...(if selectors priority are equal)

try replacing your media query and other selectors

in RWD it's always better to add media queries with larger values below smaller ones
just like bootstrap does

```
.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-md-row {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

use max instead of min
Ex : (max-width:69px)